# Error compile board LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini

Tags: esp8266, programming, library, compile

I have a wemos d1 mini and a mpu 6060 sensor. I am trying to send the data from the sensor to Firebase. However i have come across a hurdle which i cant seem to solve. This is my error, can you help me out with this issue?

Error compiling for board LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini.

```
In file included from C:\Users\Zakaria\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/Firebase.h:30:0,

                 from C:\Users\Zakaria\Desktop\WORKING_ACCELERAMETOR_BACKUP\WORKING_ACCELERAMETOR_BACKUP.ino:4:

C:\Users\Zakaria\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/FirebaseObject.h:109:11: error: StaticJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6

     std::shared_ptr<StaticJsonBuffer<FIREBASE_JSONBUFFER_SIZE>> buffer_;

           ^

In file included from C:\Users\Zakaria\Desktop\WORKING_ACCELERAMETOR_BACKUP\WORKING_ACCELERAMETOR_BACKUP.ino:4:0:

C:\Users\Zakaria\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/Firebase.h:86:11: error: StaticJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6

   std::shared_ptr<StaticJsonBuffer<FIREBASE_JSONBUFFER_SIZE>> buffer_;

           ^

Using library FirebaseJson at version 2.3.3 in folder: C:\Users\Zakaria\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseJson 
Using library firebase-arduino-master at version 0.1 in folder: C:\Users\Zakaria\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master 
Using library ArduinoJson at version 6.15.0 in folder: C:\Users\Zakaria\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson 
Using library ESP8266HTTPClient at version 1.2 in folder: C:\Users\Zakaria\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient 
Using library ESP8266WiFi at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Users\Zakaria\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi 
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Users\Zakaria\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\libraries\Wire 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini.
```

Comment: it says: "error: StaticJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6". so install ArduinoJson 5.x or do the upgrade steps